# NPER Function using repayments that increase over 5 years (Excel)

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a mortgage calculator that forecasts the number of months it will take to pay off the loan.

I have successfully done this for a basic calculation where the monthly payment doesn't change but what I need is a calculation that works for payments increasing over 5 years.

I have uploaded my spreadsheet to Dropbox at the following link as it might be easier to understand if you can see what I am doing:

[Example spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1fg47837cymjv0k/Payment%20Mortgage%20Calculator.xlsx?dl=0)

The value in V6 is the one that I want to display the months it will take to pay off the loan.

I use the basic loan details in cells G5,G6 and G7 and the monthly repayment in V5.

I then need to run this calculation to determine the monthly payment for year one (B12):

```
$G$8+(($B$16*52/12)*$B$12)+$G$9
```

This gives me the actual monthly payment. I then need to repeat these steps for years 2,3,4 and 5 in cells D12, F12, H12 and J12. So for example year five I would use the following formula:

```
$G$8+(($J$16*52/12)*$J$12)+$G$9
```

The formula I am using to actually get the monthly payments forecast is:

```
=ROUNDUP(NPER(G6/12,V5,-G5),0)
```

Now I understand that to calculate a basic loan works but I need the repayments to increase year on year and for the total months for the repayment to reflect this.

Please can someone suggest a way around this problem or point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This does exactly what I need and provides a detailed answer with a template:

[Experts Exchange example with explanation](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/A_3331-Fixed-Rate-Loan-Amortization-Schedule-with-Optional-Extra-Principal-Payments.html)